# Final steps in the General Number Field Sieve

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, factoring

I try to understand the General Number Field Sieve, based on Michal Case paper "[A beginner's guide to the general number field sieve](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.219.2389&rep=rep1&type=pdf)". I was able to reproduce some results from the example, i.e. $$\prod_{(a,b)\in V} (a+bm) = 459997127517955195582606376960000$$ and $$\prod_{(a,b)\in V}(a+b\theta)=58251363820606365*\theta^{2}+149816899035790332*\theta+75158930297695972$$

Now I need to compute square roots in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$. But the next step result from the paper seems to be incorrect, since $$459997127517955195582606376960000 \neq 2553045317222400^{2}$$

How should I compute both square roots to get the results presented in the paper? How to calculate square root in $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$? Next, how can I find the mapping $\phi$ required in the next step of the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
h(x):=58251363820606365x^2+149816899035790332x+75158930297695972
$$

What you want to solve is
$$
(u+vx+wx^2)^2 \equiv h(x) \pmod{x^3+15x^2+29x+8}
$$
so a necessary condition is 
$$
(u+vx+wx^2)^2 \equiv h(x) \pmod{x^3+15x^2+29x+8,p}
$$
for any prime $p$.

The reason for introducing modulo $p$ is because the equation is much easier to solve to get an initial solution (for small $p$'s), plus you can then use lifting to lift the equations to larger modulus (from modulo $p^k$ to $p^{k+1}$ in the example below, but in practice it should be $p^k$ to $p^{2k}$ for efficiency).

One important note here is the the absolute values of $u,v,w$ are bounded, so once you have lifted the solutions to large enough values they will be correct even without the modulus $p^k$ (If one of $u,v,w$ is too large then after modulo $f(x)$ you must have an overly huge coefficient). This answer is kind of incomplete since I will not touch upon how to bound it efficiently.

This $p$-adic lifting method is how some of the more modern methods solve the squareroot step ([For example this.](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00756838/en))

---

It is much simpler to work with $p$ such that $f(x):= x^3+15x^2+29x+8$ is irreducible modulo $p$, but not strictly necessary. For example if you chose a $p$ such that $x^3+15x^2+29x+8$ splits into $3$ factors $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$, you can still solve
$$
(u+vx+wx^2)^2 \equiv 58251363820606365x^2+149816899035790332x+75158930297695972 \pmod{x-r_i,p}
$$
for each of the $r_i$.

Then you can combine the results (modulo large enough $p^k$) via CRT to get a solution modulo $(f(x),p^k)$. The problem with this method is there are $2^3$ way to form the final CRT, since each $x-r_i$ has two possibilities (if $g(x)$ is a squareroot then $-g(x)$ also is one). This can be resolve by simply trying each one of them, so the method can still work. In particular since the linear form $\pmod{x-r_i,p^k}$ is simpler so there could be some advantages (which is why the paper earlier proposes it).

---

As an example, I chose $p=5$ so that $x^3+15x^2+29x+8$ is irreducible. So start by solving
$$
(u+vx+wx^2)^2 \equiv h(x)\equiv 2x+2 \pmod{x^3+15x^2+29x+8,5}
$$
By trying all values, we find that $1+x+4x^2$ works. A better solution would have been to treat it as a squareroot problem in a finite field of size $5^3$.

Next, we lift the solution to modulo $5^2$.
$$
((1+5u)+(1+5v)x+(4+5w)x^2)^2 \equiv h(x) \equiv 15x^2+7x+22 \pmod{x^3+15x^2+29x+8,5^2}
$$
Since $0\leq u,v,w < 5$ it's still easy to bruteforce them, though not exactly the best way. Notice that this part is also incomplete since I did not really justify why there is only one solution for the lift.

After some bruteforcing, we get $(u,v,w)= (3,2,0)$. Hence
$$
(16+11x+4x^2)^2 \equiv h(x) \pmod{x^3+15x^2+29x+8,5^2}
$$

Continuing in this manner:
$$
\begin{align}
(16+36 x+29 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^3}\\
(141+161 x+154 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^4}\\
(766+1411 x+779 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^5}\\
(13266 + 7661 x + 779 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^6}\\
(44516 + 7661 x + 63279 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^7}\\
(122641 + 7661 x + 375779 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^8}\\
(903891 + 398286 x + 1547654 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^9}\\
(8716391 + 4304536 x + 9360154 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^{10}}\\
(8716391 + 14070161 x + 19125779 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^{11}}\\
(8716391 + 62898286 x + 214438279 x^2)^2 &\equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x),5^{12}}
\end{align}
$$

At each step, if $g(x)=u+vx+wx^2$ is a solution modulo $(f(x),5^k)$, then so is $(-u-vx-wx^2)$ and hence $\overline g(x)=(5^k-u)+(5^k-v)x+(5^k-w)x^2$ is also a solution.

If $h(x)$ is indeed a square $r(x)^2$, then after sufficient steps we ought to arrive at the solution via either $g(x)$ or $\overline g(x)$ (once our solutions are "large enough"). Indeed, at step $12$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\overline g(x) &= 5^{12}-8716391 + (5^{12}-62898286) x + (5^{12}-214438279) x^2\\
&= 235424234 + 181242339 x + 29702346 x^2
\end{align*}
$$
and we can check that 
$$
\overline g(x)^2 \equiv h(x) \pmod{f(x)}
$$

i.e. the squareroot we want is $235424234 + 181242339 x + 29702346 x^2$. (Remark again that there is a way to know when we have done enough lifting.)

---

Now taking the homomorphism $x\mapsto m=31 \pmod n$, 
$$
\phi((235424234 + 181242339 x + 29702346 x^2)^2) \equiv 34397891249^2 \pmod n
$$
For the rational side we have
$$
45999712751795195582606376960000 = 6782308806873600^2
$$
Therefore this gives
$$
6782308806873600^2 \equiv 34397891249^2 \pmod{n = 45113}
$$
which is correct since both sides is $\equiv 27005$. Finally we take the gcd:
$$
\gcd(6782308806873600+34397891249,45113) = 229
$$
which solves the problem.

Comment: Actually the paper goes into how to use the norm function alpha^((p^d-1)/(p-1)) to somehow avoid having ambiguity in the positive/negative square root.  But no example is given and determining what is positive or negative in that regard looks problematic.  But again, since noone seems to understand how to do this properly, this answer is also lacking this key bit of sufficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer to another question ([In the general number field sieve, do we need to know whether powers of elements in the algebraic factor base divide an element $a+b\theta$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216692/in-the-general-number-field-sieve-do-we-need-to-know-whether-powers-of-elements)) we know that the mentioned paper has some major and minor errors.

Matthew E. Briggs in his thesis [An Introduction to the General Number Field Sieve](https://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/doc/briggs_gnfs_thesis.pdf) describes the method to successfully perform the computations. It sums up to the following algorithm:

1. Determining applicable finite fields

> The first stage in computing $x = φ(β) \pmod{p}$ (...) is to find a number of finite fields that are “compatible” with $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, which boils down to finding prime integers $p$ for which $f(x)$ remains irreducible modulo $p$.

2. Finding square roots in finite field
3. Using the CRT - once square roots in the finite fields are known, the Chineses Remainder Theorem can be used to complete the computations.

Notice that this approach eliminates the need to compute an explicit value of square root in $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$. As stated by the author, in practice we never calculate this value.

The second value is calculated simply as square root in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If you could point to a good version of finding the square root which is complicated, but that deals with the norm being positive or negative, that would be helpful, as such details are never treated with a good example in the paper.