# How to compute a smooth number over a factor base in General Number Field Sieve (GNFS) factoring algorithm?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, factoring, maximal-and-prime-ideals, sieve-theory

Following [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280463963_A_Guide_to_General_Number_Field_Sieve_for_Integer_Factorization) on page 12, I understand the first steps of the general number field sieve (GNFS) algorithm for factoring as follows:

---

**Step 1:**

Let

$$N = 77$$

and choose

$$m = 4$$

Then

$$N=77 = 1(4^3) + 0(4^2) + 3(4^1) + 1(4^0)$$

so

$$f = x^3 + 3x + 1$$

Let $\alpha$ be any root of this equation, ie. $f(\alpha) = 0$.

---

**Step 2:**

Choose a set of small prime exponents basis

$$p = \{2,3,5,7\}$$

and compute pairs of integers $(i, p)$ where $f(i) = 0 \mod{p}$:

$$\{(2,3),(1,5),(2,5),(4,7)\}$$

Further choose a few prime numbers not already previously included in $p$:

$$q = \{11,13\}$$

and compute pairs of integers $(i, q)$ where $f(i) = 0 \mod{q}$:

$$\{(4,11),(11,13)\}$$

---

I am having trouble **sieving** this in order to get the smooth pair results next, for instance:

$$smoothpair \rightarrow (-10,1)$$

I can verify a smooth number on the integer prime exponents basis

$$ a + bm = -10 + 1(4) = -6 = -2^1 3^1$$

but I don't understand what it means to be smooth number $a+b\alpha$ over the factor base $\{(2,3),(1,5),(2,5),(4,7)\}$?

---

So in summary, the question is **what needs to be calculated to verify** whether

$$-10 + 1(\alpha)$$ is a smooth number over the factor base $\{(2,3),(1,5),(2,5),(4,7)\}$?

---

Edit: there is a comment by @KevinJohnson [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216692/in-the-general-number-field-sieve-do-we-need-to-know-whether-powers-of-elements):

[image]

The condition that there exist some pair $(r,p)$ for which

$$a + br \mod{p} = 0$$ seems to be always satisfied for $(a,b)$ to be flagged smooth over the factor base$(r,p)$:

[image]

Randomly constructed integer pairs set $(a,b)$ generally never satisfy this condition 100/100:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Step 3** may been completed according to [[this]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280463963_A_Guide_to_General_Number_Field_Sieve_for_Integer_Factorization) (page 14):

[image]

where the formulas are

$$N_1 = a - bm$$

$$N_2 = b^3 - f(\frac{a}{b})$$

and $QC$ are quadratic residue flags computed very similarly to the Legendre symbol (explained in ref).

**Step 4:**

Construct matrix M, with each row with entries cycled modulo $2$ as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix} sign_{N_1} & 2^a & 3^b & 5^c & 7^d & 3^e & 5^f & 5^g & 7^h & QC_1 & QC_2\end{bmatrix}^T$$

For instance the first row becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&1 \end{bmatrix}^T$$

$N_2$ composition in the diagram is ambiguous since there are actually $2$  different entries of base $5$ in the factor base which have been combined under the table:

[image]

[image]

It can be easily verified that the 3 solutions to

$$MX = 0$$

are indeed (working in modulo $2$):

[image]

[image]

**Step 5:**

$$X_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

implies

the solution pairs set

$$\{(-10,1),(-4,1),(-3,1),(-1,2)\}$$

Thus since $m=4$,

$$LHS = (-10 - 1(4))(-4-1(4))(-3-1(4))(-1-2(4)) = 7056$$

$$\sqrt{LHS} = 84$$

and by residue of polynomial long division

$$RHS = (-10 - 1(x))(-4-1(x))(-3-1(x))(-1-2(x)) mod {f(x)} = 175 x^2 + 215x + 85$$

It can be verified by reverse computation that the polynomial square root

$$\sqrt{RHS} \mod{(x^3+3x+1)} = -3x^2+14x-1 $$

Substituting $x=m$,

$$\sqrt{RHS} =7 \mod{(x^3+3x+1)}$$

Finally,

$$gcd(\sqrt{LHS}+\sqrt{RHS}, 77) = gcd(84+7,7) = gcd(91,7) = 7$$

is a factor of $N=77$.

---

Alternative numerical factor base calculation:

[image]

giving the modulo-2 matrix

[image]

which has a solution for example:

[image]

in which the included products are of $(a,b)$ pairs as follows:

[image]

which gives an integer square root on the LHS:

[image]

and a polynomial on the RHS (in ascending powers or $x^i$):

[image]

whose polynomial root modulo $1 + 3x + 0x^2 + x^3$ is:

[image]

which when evaluated at $m=4$ gives:

[image]

Finally,

$$LHS+RHS = 504+196=700$$

so

$$gcd(700,N) = gcd(700,77) = 7$$

[image]

is a factor of N.